# AngularJS foreach delay loop

Tags: angularjs, loops, foreach, timeout

I want to use delay in my `angular.foreach` loop. I have a list and I want to display them one by one with 2 seconds periods.

```
 angular.forEach(vm.SimulationResult, function (value, key) {
                    timeout2 = $timeout(function () {
                        vm.Alerts.push({ msg: value.MainStatus });
                    }, 2000);
                });
```

what should I do ?

Comment: What is the structure of `vm.SimulationResult`?

Comment: Might be worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: is that important ? It is a list with primitive types. @SiddharthAjmera

Answer (score 5):

Take advantage of the fact that $timeout returns a promise and chain the promises together so that each one starts another promise timeout that will push the next alert:

```
let promise = $timeout();
angular.forEach(vm.SimulationResult, function(value, key) {
     promise = promise.then(function() {
         vm.Alerts.push({ msg: value.MainStatus });
         return $timeout(2000);
     });
});
```

(make sure your version of angular is up to date as older versions didn't let you omit the callback function in a timeout)

Comment: Worked for me (AngularJS 1.5.8)

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Nice! Worked with Angular 1.6.2